# iPhone 7 Plus Battery Life draining?

Tags: iphone, battery, notifications

I feel like my iPhone 7 Plus battery life has gotten seriously bad at the point where I sometimes run trough 2 full charges a day.

I got the iPhone in mid-November.

I get between 4-5 hours of usage time and maybe 10-12 hours of standby.
And I wouldn't really say I'm giving it a heavy load.

I don't really have much push notifications enabled. The main push notification is Gmail really which I get between 10-15 notifications a day.

What do you guys think? I've read a lot of people getting at least 7 hours of usage under a more heavy load.

Answer (score 1):

How many cycles do you have on the battery? If you have lost >20% of your 
full charge less than ~200 cycles in, your phone is defective and eligible for service.

Failing that, you can go to the Battery tab of Settings and see which apps drain your battery the most. Quit any ones you don't need by double-clicking the home button and swiping up on them.

You can always enable Low-power mode all the time if necessary.

P.S. I have a 7+, and I get a full day (8+ hrs) between Clash Royale, texting, and the occasional web page.